# Why do some css @import commands use url() while others just place the string

Tags: css

Example directly from my CSS file:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700');
```

I purchased a beautiful theme for my WordPress site and some of the CSS fonts are imported like that. I am combining all these, and I'm just not sure of the difference.

I did some research and notice that [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) also flips between the 2 in their examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import) specification:

> The following lines are equivalent in meaning and illustrate both
>   '@import' syntaxes (one with "url()" and one with a bare string):
>
> @import "mystyle.css"; 
>   @import url("mystyle.css");

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct and they are equivalent.

This is a quote from [W3C: Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) — The Official Definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#at-ruledef-import):

> The syntax of `@import` is:
>
> ```
> @import [ <url> | <string> ] <media-query-list>? ;
> ```
>
> Where the `<url>` or `<string>` gives the URL of the style sheet to be imported, and the optional `<media-query-list>` (the import conditions) states the conditions under which it applies.
>
> If a `<string>` is provided, it must be interpreted as a url with the same value.